# jQuery UI accordion won't initiate after an ajax call

Tags: jquery-ui

I have an accordion control on an asp.net webforms page (using a master page...) that won't initialize after an ajax call I'm making to load the accordion's content. The page definitely has the references to the jquery and jquery-ui files (it works fine when I have static content in it). Where it breaks down is when I try to load it via the ajax call...

Master page header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

My aspx page markup:

```
<asp:content id="Content3" runat="Server" contentplaceholderid="mainContent">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Catalog.aspx.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(Catalog.InitPage);
  </script>
  <div id="accordion" style="width: 850px;"></div>
</asp:content>
```

the javascript (in a separate file, behaves the same if it's all on the page as well):

```
Catalog = {

    BuildAccordion: function (results) {
        var accordion = $('#accordion');
        $.each(results.d, function (index, category) {
            $(accordion).append('<div>' + category.CategoryName + '</div>');
            $.each(category.Courses, function (index, courseItem) {
                // will be adding more content here once it's all working...
            });
        });
        Catalog.InitAccordion();
    },

    InitAccordion: function() {
        $('#accordion').accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: 'content'
        });
    },

    InitPage: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebServices/GlobalWM.asmx/GetCourseCatalog",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: Catalog.BuildAccordion
        });
    }
};
```

When the page runs, I'm getting the content of the accordion ok but the error that I get is

```
TypeError:  $(...).accordion is not a function
```

(comes from the first line of the InitAccordion function...) and the accordion isn't, well, an accordion. What am I missing?

Comment: did you import that library ? because i can't see it between the imported `script` tags

Comment: That's being done on the master page (forgot to mention that...) and they are on the rendered page in the browser...I added the relevant bits from the master page...

Comment: Do you have more than one version of jQuery somewhere in there..?

Comment: No, there is only one reference to the jQuery library in the site. I actually got around this by using nested repeaters and simply data binding instead of building everything in javascript.